# If findstr doesn't find anything it leaves a weird symbol in the file

Tags: batch-file, findstr

So if I run findstr and it doesn't find any matching strings it leaves this weird symbol in the file instead:

And it does that at the end of *almost* all of my files as well. Is there a way to get rid of that or stop it from happening? Later I have it check if the file is empty or not to set a true/false and that symbol is screwing with those results. I have alot of checks in the same program running one after the other, is there something I need to do between them that will stop it?

As an example, this code doesn't do that:

```
ECHO Scanning files for Risks
(
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /L "android:allowBackup android:backupagent" AndroidManifest.xml') DO (
    SET "line=%%a"
    SET "line=!line:*android:allowBackup=!"
    SET "line=!line:*android:backupagent=!"
    FOR /F "delims=<" %%b in (!line!) DO ECHO %%b
)) > ScanResults.txt
```

But this one does:

```
ECHO Scanning files for Risks
(
FOR /F "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /S "web" *.smali') DO (
    SET "line=%%b"
    SET "line=!line:*web=!"
    FOR /F "delims=<>" %%b in ("!line!") DO ECHO %%a:%%b
)) > ScanResults.txt
```

UPDATE: Even with the two things added it still puts the weird symbol into the text file instead of having it empty

```
 ECHO Scanning files for Risks
    (
    FOR /F "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /S "web" *.smali 2^>NUL') DO (
        SET "line=%%b"
        SET "line=!line:*web=!"
        FOR /F "delims=^<^>" %%b in ("!line!") DO ECHO %%a:%%b
    )) > ScanResults.txt
```

UPDATE: To further clarify I'm searching a variety of files as previously stated, the most common being JSON and smali files in order to double check my own work. But really it searches through everything, the code is just a series of searches like the code above with just `*.smali` changed to `*.xml` or `*.json` or whatever is needed. So the section of code that is producing the weird symbol in its search looks like this:

```
ECHO off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

(
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /S "web" AndroidManifest.xml') DO (
SET "line=%%a"
SET "line=!line:*web=!"
FOR /F "delims=<>" %%b in ("!line!") DO ECHO %%b
)) > ScanResults1.txt

REM scans all JSON files
(
FOR /F "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /S "web" *.json') DO (
    SET "line=%%b"
    SET "line=!line:*web=!"
    FOR /F "delims=<>" %%b in ("!line!") DO ECHO %%a:%%b
)) > ScanResults2.txt

REM scans all html files
(
FOR /F "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /S "web" *.html') DO (
    SET "line=%%b"
    SET "line=!line:*webv=!"
    FOR /F "delims=<>" %%b in ("!line!") DO ECHO %%a:%%b
)) > ScanResults3.txt

REM scans all xml files
(
FOR /F "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /S "web" *.xml') DO (
    SET "line=%%b"
    SET "line=!line:*web=!"
    FOR /F "delims=<>" %%b in ("!line!") DO ECHO %%a:%%b
)) > ScanResults4.txt

REM scans all smali files
(
FOR /F "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /S "web" *.smali') DO (
    SET "line=%%b"
    SET "line=!line:*web=!"
    FOR /F "delims=<>" %%b in ("!line!") DO ECHO %%a:%%b
)) > ScanResults5.txt

COPY ScanResults1.txt + ScanResults2.txt + ScanResults3.txt + ScanResults4.txt + ScanResults5.txt ScanResultsA.txt
DEL ScanResults1.txt
DEL ScanResults2.txt
DEL ScanResults3.txt
DEL ScanResults4.txt
DEL ScanResults5.txt

:eof
```

The output file looks like:

[image]

That's the weird symbol I keep getting when it doesn't find anything. It won't keep it if its copied and pasted over so I had to do a picture.

Comment: The obvious difference is that only the working one uses this format: `FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN ("Text string to process") DO command`

Comment: I would advise you to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45762959/edit) your question to include the content of a genuine input file, the exact code you are telling us outputs a weird symbol and the genuine content of the output file with that weird symbol. Without those things, I'm not anticipating that you'll get a solution due to the broadness of your question.

Comment: I added as much detail as I can, it's literally searching through gigs of files though so it wouldn't be possible to put everything it's looking through for testing use. I did reclarify what types of files it goes through, what it's looking for, and what it's outputting when it doesn't find anything. Let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no finds, output should be empty and nothing passed to the for (code block)
except an error message from findstr itself not redirected to nul.

So append  `2^>NUL` to the `findstr`

```
FOR /F "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /S "web" *.smali 2^>NUL') DO (
```